# How to get Android Bugs Reports Data?

Tags: dataset, stack-trace

Since Android is open source, I guess there won't be problem if I use the data for my project. I want to do a project where I need a dataset that contains bug reports that many users have sent across the world, and I want to predict the severity of the bug by analyzing the report either by performing text mining on the description of the report or by stacktracing. But, the main problem is Dataset. Can someone tell me how do I get the dataset for this project? Also, if you have any idea on this project, help me out.

Comment: While the code for the Android project is open source, the individual error logs belong to the app developers, ROM makers, and device manufacturers.

Comment: so isn't there any way to get the bug reports? There is a google issue tracker where people can post the issue. if i can see the post i guess scraping that would make my dataset complete.

Comment: Data requests are oft-topic for stackexchange. You can flag for a moderator to move this to opendata.SE